# String manipulation of `CI_COMMIT_TAG` used by `environment:url` in GitLab pipeline

Tags: gitlab

In short:
Find a way to do simple parsing of a variable that is already available to `environment:url` as part of a pipeline job.

The particulars: A job that is triggered by a git tag following a git-flow release finish, such as `v1.32.7`. GitLab makes this available in `CI_BUILD_TAG`. What I would like is to to be able to only use the major version part, e.g. `v1` in `environment:name` and `environment:url`.

Does anyone have a clever way of solving this? I've considered maybe having hooks that insert this value into the code itself, but I'm curious as to what solutions others have arrived at.

---

I'm aware that `GitLab` has strict limitations as to where variables can be expanded, and which variables can be used when. Here is an overview: https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/ci/variables/where_variables_can_be_used.html#gitlab-internal-variable-expansion-mechanism

My question is regarding the use of data that is already available to GitLab, such as the variables in question. And not the act of transferring data evaluated by runners to GitLab, something that is fairly problematic given the architecture, and otherwise discussed here:

- https://gitlab.com/gitlab-org/gitlab-ce/issues/27921
- https://gitlab.com/gitlab-org/gitlab-ce/issues/28314

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately, that can't be done strictly within a `.gitlab-ci.yml` file. It's a technical limitation. The environment `name` and `url` are evaluated on the GitLab (server) side, not by the runners. So, there's no access to variables declared in the script block, as you've already discovered. I've yet to find any clever workarounds.

One possibility, related to your comment about “hooks that insert this value into the code itself,” is to have something call the GitLab API to run a pipeline for a tag that parses out the `v1` part and passes it in as a variable. Pipeline variables can be used for environment names and urls.

https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/api/pipelines.html#create-a-new-pipeline